# How to determine the source of a memory leak from a Chrome heap dump

Tags: javascript, memory, knockout.js, memory-leaks, google-dfp

I am attempting to debug a memory leak on [Playlist.com](http://www.playlist.com) and am unable to determine where exactly the leak is coming from.  The main app code is a Knockout.js-based application, and there are also Google DFP (DoubleClick for Publishers) ads on the page.  The app does things with pushState and HTML5 history (PJAX-style), so it's possible the ads are interacting with that code somehow.

Anyways, if you leave the site running, the memory just keeps on climbing.

I've been following guides to use the Chrome heap dumps to see what's in the heap, however, I'm not entirely sure how to interpret the results or know what goes with what.  Any guidance on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Not sure if this is the best place to post this, but I don't know where else to go.  IRC and the SO Javascript chat room have been unhelpful thus far.

Comment: > SO Javascript chat room have been unhelpful thus far.  Great way to get help from us.

Comment: Just thus far - I have hopes :)

Comment: As an example of a guide: http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/08/finding-memory-leaks.html